# Groupby and sum only one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

So I have a dataframe, `df1`, that looks like the following:

```
       A      B      C
1     foo    12    California
2     foo    22    California
3     bar    8     Rhode Island
4     bar    32    Rhode Island
5     baz    15    Ohio
6     baz    26    Ohio
```

I want to group by column `A` and then sum column `B` while keeping the value in column `C`. Something like this:

```
      A       B      C
1    foo     34    California
2    bar     40    Rhode Island
3    baz     41    Ohio
```

The issue is, when I say

```
df.groupby('A').sum()
```

column `C` gets removed, returning

```
      B
A
bar  40
baz  41
foo  34
```

How can I get around this and keep column `C` when I group and sum?

Comment: Can you just `groupby` A and C? If every value of A doesn't map 1 to 1 to a value of C, then what you're asking isn't possible. If they do map 1 to 1, it should be no trouble to `groupby` both

Comment: Yea got it, I had been trying to do multiple values but hadn't been using the proper format which caused me to think I couldn't use multiple values. Thanks!

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to include C in your groupby (the groupby function can accept a list).

Give this a try:

```
df.groupby(['A','C'])['B'].sum()
```

One other thing to note, if you need to work with df after the aggregation you can also use the `as_index=False` option to return a dataframe object. This one gave me problems when I was first working with Pandas. Example:

```
df.groupby(['A','C'], as_index=False)['B'].sum()
```

Comment: Yup, I hadn't realized I needed the [] which made me think you couldn't group multiple columns. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! If you could accept the answer (green check) I'd greatly appreciate it. Best of luck!

Comment: Maybe we should add the comment that if we want to export this and keep the headers we need to add this line in the end: `df.to_csv("output.csv", header=True, index=True)`

Answer (score 22):

If you don't care what's in your column `C` and just want the `nth` value, you could just do this:

```
df.groupby('A').agg({'B' : 'sum',
                     'C' : lambda x: x.iloc[n]})
```

Comment: Getting error on this line: 'c' : lambda x: x.iloc[n]} . the error is : NameError: name 'n' is not defined

Comment: n is just an example, you can put any integer you like there.

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to use `groupby.agg` and use the `first` method on column `"C"`.

```
out = df.groupby('A', as_index=False, sort=False).agg({'B':'sum', 'C':'first'})
```

Output:

```
     A   B             C
0  foo  34    California
1  bar  40  Rhode Island
2  baz  41          Ohio
```