# python panads group by losing column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

There are 3 columns,

```
ACCOUNT, DATE, AMOUNT
```

I am trying to do the following in pandas, and plan to use the "sum" column after the group by output dataframe to do more works:

```
df_group_by=df.groupby('account').agg({'amount': [np.size, np.sum]},as_index=False).reset_index() # equal to "SELECT ACCOUNT, SUM(amount) as sum FROM table GROUP BY ACCOUNT;"

print (df_group['sum'])
```

and then I got the following error message:

```
KeyError: 'sum
```

I don't understand.  Anyone could help?  Thank you!

I am in python 3.6 & pandas 0.19.2

Answer (score 0):

df_group is a multi-index data frame, you can access the 'sum' column by df_group['amount']['sum']

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

[Pandas Groupby and Sum Only One Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985053/pandas-groupby-and-sum-only-one-column)

```
df_group_by=df.groupby(['account'], as_index=False)['amount'].sum()

print (df_group['amount'])
```